# Get,Set using Lists in C# ...Help Needed

Tags: c#

I need to read a CSV file in C# and drop the data into a list and then dump the data to a SQL Database database.

The class I'm interested using is using CsvHelper.

This is two sample data in the CSV File:

```
1,2013-05-14,NISSAN,059 7013,1995,VAN,Deisel,NISSAN,0000,NISSAN,Red,MARADANA,op1,description,p1.jpg+p2.jpg+p3.jpg,r1+r2+r3

2,2013-05-14,NISSAN2,059-7013,1995,VAN,Deisel,NISSAN,0000,NISSAN,Red,MARADANA,op1,description,p1.jpg+p2.jpg+p3.jpg,r1+r2+r3
```

This is the class for the CSV file

```
class Vehicle
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ClosingDate { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Reg { get; set; }
        public string YearOfManufacture { get; set; }
        public string VehicleType { get; set; }
        public string Fuel { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Mileage { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Colour { get; set; }
        public string VehicleYard { get; set; }
        public string BasicOptions { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<string> Photos { get; set; }
        public List<string> Regions { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried and read the CSV file using this code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CsvHelperRead();

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void CsvHelperRead()
        {

            CsvConfiguration config = new CsvConfiguration();
            config.HasHeaderRecord = false;

            using (var reader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\afshandc\Desktop\0729\vTest.csv"), config))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetField(1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to read the CSV file and drop it to this list.

```
 class CSV
    {
        public List<Vehicle> ReadVechileCSV()
        {







        }
    }
```

Comment: Your post missing section where you describe problem you have writing the code. So far there are only vague requirements...

Comment: I would advice you first to use `""data1"",""data2""` in your CSV, I think your description will contain commas in the future and that will corrupt your records. Then you can trust on other solutions like suggested by @No Idea For Name

Comment: _Off-topic:_ your `Vehicle` has too much strings while respective data-types exist in C#. Basically, while creating this kind of applications it's always a good idea to have some helper utility that hides this ugly parsing at the top level of application.

Comment: @PLB Ill consider it next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `CsvHelperRead` you can do:

```
using (var reader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\afshandc\Desktop\0729\vTest.csv"), config))
     {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           string line = reader.GetField(1);
           string[] classParams = line.Split(',');
           Vehicle v = new Vehicle()
          {
           ID = int.Parse(classParams[0]),
           ClosingDate = classParams[1],
           Model = classParams[2],
           Reg = classParams[3],
           YearOfManufacture = classParams[4],
           VehicleType = classParams[5],
           Fuel = classParams[6],
           Brand = classParams[7],
           Mileage = classParams[8],
           Make = classParams[9],
           Colour = classParams[10],
           VehicleYard = classParams[11],
           BasicOptions = classParams[12],
           Description = classParams[13],
           Photos = GetJoinedByPlus(classParams[14]),
           Regions = GetJoinedByPlus(classParams[15])
          };
        }
     }

  private List<string> GetJoinedByPlus(string p)
  {
     List<string> rtVal = new List<string>();
     rtVal.AddRange(p.Split('+'));
     return rtVal;
  }
```

assuming you have a constructor for vehicle the receive it's params..

Comment: You could also use object initialization (and avoid having to write a constructor).

Comment: Although this creates a singular Vehicle for each line read, this isn't persisted into a List of Vehicles as specified in the question.

Comment: Alright Ill Try That!

Comment: edited, look now @DrekJohn

Comment: +1 for handling the two `List<T>` (was wondering if anyone was ever going to catch that part :) ).

Comment: And Thanks for Helping out Guys Really Appreciate it!